# How to calculate arrays of objects intersection with custom comparison function?

Tags: php

I have two arrays of objects and I need to get array of objects which are present in both arrays, comparing them with custom callback function.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Some {
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;

    public function __construct($prop1, $prop2)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
        $this->prop2 = $prop2;
    }
}

$arr1 = [new Some(1, 2), new Some(2, 3), new Some(3, 4)];
$arr2 = [new Some(2, 3), new Some(1, 2)];

$intersection = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, function ($el1, $el2) {
    return ($el1->prop1 === $el2->prop1) && ($el1->prop2 === $el2->prop2) ? 0 : 1;
});

print_r($intersection);
```

And what I get is:

> Array (
>       [1] => Some Object
>           (
>               [prop1] => 2
>               [prop2] => 3
>           )
>
> )

While I obviously want to get two objects which props are identical ((1, 2) and (2, 3).

What's wrong with this uintersect? How to achieve what I need?

Comment: intersect function first sorted arrays, so you need have understanding haw one object less than another, and return -1, 0, 1 as result of comparing. Else, if you only can answer that objects are equal or not, you should scan second array for each item of the first one

Comment: Now result of the code depends on order of objects in your arrays

Comment: I added a third property for a "marker" and it never compared `$arr1[1]` with `$arr2[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Intersect function first sorted arrays, so you need have understanding haw one object less than another, and return -1, 0, 1 as result of comparing. Else, if you only can answer that objects are equal or not, you should scan second array for each item of the first one – splash58 13 mins ago. Now result of the code depends on order of objects in your arrays

To use intersect function you can create a function to compare two objects as below

```
class Some {
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;

    static function compare($el1, $el2) {
       $r = $el1->prop1 - $el2->prop1;
       return $r ? $r : ($el1->prop2 - $el2->prop2);         
    }


    public function __construct($prop1, $prop2)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
        $this->prop2 = $prop2;
    }
}

$arr1 = [new Some(1, 2), new Some(2, 3), new Some(3, 4)];
$arr2 = [new Some(2, 3), new Some(1, 2)];

$intersection = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, ['Some','compare']);

print_r($intersection);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4d798c79fc314be78cc4fecf74626d7bc195ebb)

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to make function to compare objects, PHP itself checks that such objects are equal. So you can use simple code with in_array function

```
$intersection = array();
foreach($arr1 as $x) { 
    if (in_array($x, $arr2)) {
        $intersection[] = $x;
    }
}
print_r($intersection);
```

Comment: In real task I have strings instead of numbers in that props. I need function to work with any content in that props, just saying "identical/non-identical". Why do I need to sort content if it can be anything - objects, arrays, strings?

Comment: You don't need to sort them. Intersect works so. I've written - you can make two-level loop to find duplicates. In that case,  "identical/non-identical" will be enough

Comment: @Audiophile if not use intersect, php will compare your objects by itself: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6df0384274db918dc4be1c3793324ae992724b3

Comment: Thumbs up for the object comparison hint. PHP compares objects like `$object1 == $object2` or even `$object1 === $object2`.